# Rails Elastic Search Error "The stack size specified is too small, Specify at least 160k Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch

I'm working on a Rails3 Project using Elasticsearch and Tire. After installing Elastic-search when I try to run it, it gives me the following error:

```
The stack size specified is too small, Specify at least 160k
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I have Java 7 and my OS is Ubuntu 12.04. How do I resolve this error?

Do I need to install Java 6, and if so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem with an older version of elasticsearch (0.19.0).
Installed 0.19.8 and it works again.
You can get it here: [elasticsearch-0.19.2.tar.gz](https://github.com/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-0.19.2.tar.gz)

good luck!

Indeed there seems a problem with java 1.7 and older versions of es.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can send the stack size option and set it to something greater then 160k when starting elasticsearch on the console

```
sudo ./bin/elasticsearch -Xss194k
```

Answer (score 2):

Increase the stack size to an amount greater than 160k.

Edit file `elasticsearch-0.xx.x/bin/elasticsearch.in.sh` at about line 34 and increase -Xss to something larger such as `-Xss256k` for example.

```
# reduce the per-thread stack size
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xss256k"
```